# What is this SVG tag and what is it doing?

Tags: template, svg

Working on a client site and found this SVG tag sitting in the template footer, but I can't figure out what the heck it's for. Anyone seen this before?

```
<svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg-filters" style="display:none;"><defs><filter id="marker-shape"><feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0 0.15" numOctaves="1" result="warp" /><feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="30" in="SourceGraphic" in2="warp" /></filter></defs></svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

The clue is in the `<feTurubulunce>` tag.  It's creating a fractal.  If you aren't familiar with [fractals](https://fractalfoundation.org/resources/what-are-fractals/), they're unending patterns.  Using the filter feTurbulence, allows you to create distortions and custom graphic textures.  From the fractals link above:

> the feTurbulence filter primitive generates and renders Perlin noise.
> This kind of noise is useful in simulating several natural phenomena
> like clouds, fire and smoke, and in generating complex texture like
> marble or granite.

The concept is used by a lot of screensavers and drawing software to create background patterns.

For more information about using the `<feTurubulence>` tag see  - https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/02/19/svg-filter-effects-creating-texture-with-feturbulence/.